# What is the difference between (a: ?string) and (a?: string) in flow type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

What is the difference between `a?: string` and `a: ?string` in Flow?

```
function concat(a: ?string, b: ?string): string {
}
```

vs

```
function concat(a?: string, b?: string): string {
}
```

Comment: Can you show example code for the usage of each?  The output will help us get to the solution together.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#optional-parameters-

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a: ?string` is a [Maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types) - actually `string | null | void` in this case.

`a?: string` is an [optional property](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-optional-object-properties)/[paramerter](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-optional-function-parameters) - `string | void`

The difference between them is that maybe type can also be (in addition to the type itself) `null` or `void`, and optional parameter only `void`.

When calling function with optional or maybe parameters `function foo(a?: string)` or `function(a: ?string)` - in both cases parameter can be omitted.

Another difference is in object properties - only optional properties can be omitted:

```
type WithOptional = {
  foo?: string;
}
type WithMaybe = {
  foo: ?string;
}

const a: WithOptional = {}; // OK
const b: WithMaybe = {}; // Error
```

Answer (score 3):

`a?: string` is an [optional parameter](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#optional-parameters-). From the docs:

> Optional parameters will accept missing, `undefined`, or matching types. But they will not accept `null`.

`a: ?string` is a [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/). From the docs:

> It’s common for JavaScript code to introduce “optional” values so that you have the option of leaving out the value or passing null instead.
>
> ...
>
> Maybe types accept the provided type as well as `null` or `undefined`. So ?number would mean `number`, `null`, or `undefined`.

So the chief difference appears to be that you can use `null` for a maybe type, but not for an optional parameter.